# leaflet third party base map providers produces errors in bookdown bs4

Tags: r, bookdown, r-leaflet

## Question

Am I missing something when implementing leaflet third party base map providers when working in `bookdown` with `bs4_book`? When I use `addProviderTiles` in other R Markdown documents I don't have an issue. However, this leaflet function does not seem to work properly in a `bookdown` `bs4` document.

## Issue

When using the leaflet function `addProviderTiles` in bookdown bs4, I get the following error.

```r
Error: path for html_dependency not found: C:/Users/<MY_USER_NAME>/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpaeEj7s
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

## Steps to reproduce

1. In RStudio, with the bookdown library installed, select File>New Project> New Directory> Book project using Bookdown>  for HTML book output select bs4_book> supply a directory name and create.
2. In `_output.yml` of the minimum working example, delete lines 6-12 so that the only output format is `bookdown::bs4_book`. Leave everything else default.
3. In `index.Rmd`, paste under the `About` heading the following leaflet example code.

```r
library(leaflet)

m <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
  addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup="The birthplace of R")
m  # Print the map
```

4. Build the book. The book builds fine and displays the leaflet map showing the birthplace of R.
5. Using examples from the leafly documentation, modify the code chunk above to instruct the map to show third party basemap providers. The final lines now read:

```r
m %>% addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.NatGeoWorldMap)
```

6. With this change in code, building the book results in the error above.

One workaround is to avoid using third party base maps. However, I would much prefer to use some of the existing third party base maps that can be normally accessed with `addProviderTiles`. Thank you in advance for any insight into how to proceed.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: No, I avoided it by moving the project to `.qmd` where the tiles work fine.

Comment: OK. Perhaps, we faced some similar issue, but choosing a different browser (firefox) solved the problem in our case.